# Flink WordCount, when is the sum calculation, where in the source code?

Tags: java, apache-flink

In the Flink WordCount calculation, when is the sum count called? Where is the implementation in the Flink source code?

Comment: --------------------------------------
).flink.17.2
).本地环境: scala WordCount ,程序在附件中 SocketWindowWordCountLocal.scala
).输入数据:
   a b a
).设置的 timeWindow(Time.seconds(20))   
).[问题]想调试Flink源码中具体在哪一步进行sum操作
-------------------------------------------------

调试:
).RecordWriter.emit()，这个时候，数据是已经flatMap,map之后的值， 函数中会一条一条数据发送(a,1),(b,1),(a,1)
).调用 StreamSink.processElement 函数打印输出结果
).没明白地方，是在调用StreamSink.processElement之前，在哪个地方调用了sum,对相同key进行了聚合操作

Comment: Please add the code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Flink1.7.2 local WordCount源码分析
概述
Flink 环境 local,版本 Flink.1.7.2
用官网示例WordCount Scala程序分析源码
本文从source、operator、sink三个方面详细分析源码实现
源码: https://github.com/opensourceteams/fink-maven-scala-2

Comment: https://github.com/opensourceteams/fink-maven-scala-2/blob/master/md/flink-local-wordCount-%E6%BA%90%E7%A0%81%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90.md